# 3 state, 3 input function with bitwise operators does not produce expected result

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is some code that I wrote up to generate a set of numbers;

```
def _tnry(x,y,z):
    a = None

    if((y == 0 & z == 0) | (x == 0 & y == 0) | (x == 0 & z == 0)):
        a = 1

    if((y == 1 & z == 1) | (x == 1 & y == 1) | (x == 1 & z == 1)):
        a = 2

    if((y == 2 & z == 2) | (x == 2 & y == 2) | (x == 2 & z == 2)):
        a = 0

    print(x,y,z,'ternary =',a )
```

I am having some problems with the output when you give the input of the following:

```
_tnry(0,1,2)
_tnry(0,2,1)
_tnry(1,0,2)
_tnry(1,2,0)
_tnry(2,0,1)
_tnry(2,1,0)
```

As far as I can see in my code `a` should not ever come out as being equal to 0, 1 or 2. I want to force it to always be `None` in the examples given.

All other output from the script is how I want it to come out.

Comment: Did you mean `or` instead of `|`, and `and` instead of `&`?

Comment: yes I did mean <code> | </code> and <code> & </code>. A good explaination is at the following link [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is-in-python)

Comment: why use `&` instead of `and` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bitwise operators `&` have higher precedence over other operators, so

```
y == 0 & z == 0
```

is actually interpreted as

```
y == (0 & z) == 0
```

Which ends up becoming

```
y == 0 == 0
```

Which is different from what you want. This applies to all your conditions.

You'll want to fix this by using another layer of parens:

```
(y == 0) & (z == 0)
```

Comment: or use `and` instead of `&`

Comment: @Jasen Which I thought at first but apparently OP knows what they're doing.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: Thank you! I didn't know that was how Python read the code internally. That is exactly what I needed to know to fix the issue.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: do you know where I can read more about how Python works internally so I can optimize the code I write in the future?

Comment: @WhitequillRiclo Glad to help. As for the inner machinations of python, you should start by perusing the docs. 95% of what you need to know is there. The rest of it can be found in the cpython developers mailing lists :)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: I will look over the docs. I've never read the documentation before. I will also consider joining the developers mailing list.  I'm more a Python programmer than a dev, so I hadn't considered joining the mailing list before.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a shorter and easier-to-debug, although maybe less clear, way to approach it (assumes all inputs are 0,1, or 2, and that you do in fact mean `or` and `and` rather than bitwise):

```
def _tnry(x,y,z):

    if len({x,y,z}) < 3: #at least two are the same:
        return (sorted([x,y,z])[1] + 1) % 3
```

If at least two are the same, then the middle one when they're sorted will be from the majority. Returns None by default, like all Python functions.

Answer (score 0):

use `and` for logical and.

```
def _tnry(x,y,z):
    a = None
    if((y == 0 and z == 0) | (x == 0 and y == 0) | (x == 0 and z == 0)):
        a = 1
    if((y == 1 and z == 1) | (x == 1 and y == 1) | (x == 1 and z == 1)):
        a = 2
    if((y == 2 and z == 2) | (x == 2 and y == 2) | (x == 2 and z == 2)):
        a = 0
    print(x,y,z,'ternary =',a )
```

if there's no need to constrain the input to 0,1,2 I would write it like this:

```
def _tnry(x,y,z):
    if y == z or x == z :
        a = z
    elif x == y : 
        a = x
    else:
        a = None
    print(x,y,z,'ternary =',a )
```